# Do all parts of a SQL SERVER expression using 'OR' get evaluated?

Tags: sql-server, expression, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

**Given:**

```
WHERE (@Id Is NULL OR @Id = Table.Id)
```

If @Id is null: the expression evaluates to true.  Does the second part @Id = Table.Id still get considered? or is it sufficient that the expression evaluates to true given that the first part is (which is the case in c#).

This is relevant because of some much more complex OR statements where it is important to know if all parts are getting evaluated.

---

**UPDATE:**

I have since found this syntax to be a good alternative

```
WHERE (Table.Id = ISNULL(@Id, Table.Id))
```

Comment: In complicated queries both sides might be run in parallel...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes they are, sometimes they aren't. SQL Server does not guarantee boolean operator short circuit, don't rely on it for correctness. See this blog entry: [Boolean Operator Short Circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/).

Complex queries that depend on @variables like this are much better written as explicit IF statements:

```
IF (@id IS NULL)
  SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
ELSE
  SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Execution plans may not be so great with a query like that.
Both will  be evaluated.

Comment: I ran the example from the blog Remus posted, "select 'Will not divide by zero!' where (@id is NULL or 1/0=0)" did not cause an error when @id is NULL