# SSRS Multi-Value Parameter Error

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

**Goal:** 
I have an SSRS report that uses a hidden parameter to capture the UserID, a multi-value drop-down parameter that displays Branches, and another multi-value parameter that will show Sales Reps related to those Branches. The idea is that the user can only view Branches and Sales Reps where their UserID is equal to the name of the Branch.

**Problem:**
If the user is given access to view the branches Chicago and New York, and selects only those Branches, the report runs fine. Data is displayed for only those two Branches.

If the user selects only Chicago an error message is displayed.

If the user Selects only New York an error message is displayed.

If the user chooses 'SELECT ALL' the report displays data for all Branches (even Branches they should not have access to).

**ERROR MESSAGE:** *Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Chicago' to data type int.*

I'm using a query in the Dataset, not a stored procedure. Should I be using a stored procedure instead?

I'm using an 'IN' operator in the WHERE CLAUSE:

```
WHERE ReportIDTable.ReportID = 1 
AND ReportIDTable.UserID = @UserID
AND ((Branch IN (@BranchID)) OR Branch = 9999)
```

I've tried using JOIN() and SPLIT() functions and I don't see a difference.

I've done a lot of research and I can't seem to get the issue solved. Any help would be much appreciated!

The @BranchID parameter is set to TEXT already and is actually populated by another query.

```
SELECT 'ZZ <Untracked Sales>' AS ParentID
UNION
SELECT ParentID
FROM     ReportDistribution WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  (ReportID = 1) AND (ReportHierarchyID = 3)
GROUP BY ParentID
```

**Main Dataset Query:**

```
SELECT 
commission_sale_history.invoice_year, 
commission_sale_history.invoice_month, 
branch.branch_description, 
commission_reps.division, 
commission_reps.rep_name, 
commission_reps.employee_id, 
commission_sale_history.customer_id, 
customer.customer_name, 
commission_sale_history.invoice_no, 
commission_sale_history.order_no, 
commission_sale_history.product_division, 
commission_sale_history.commission_type, 
commission_sale_history.sales, 
commission_sale_history.commission_cost, 
commission_sale_history.commission_amount, 
commission_sale_history.payment_date, 
commission_sale_history.invoice_date,
commission_sale_history.commission_rate, 
commission_sale_history.commission_split,
commission_reps.salary

FROM ((((commission_sale_history WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN commission_reps WITH (NOLOCK)
ON (commission_sale_history.branch_id = commission_reps.branch_id) 
AND (commission_sale_history.rep_id = commission_reps.rep_id)) 
INNER JOIN customer WITH (NOLOCK)
ON commission_sale_history.customer_id = customer.customer_id) 
INNER JOIN branch WITH (NOLOCK)
ON commission_sale_history.branch_id = branch.branch_id) 
INNER JOIN ReportIDTable WITH (NOLOCK)
ON commission_reps.rep_id = 
CASE WHEN CONVERT(int,ReportIDTable.Salesrep) = 999999
THEN commission_reps.rep_id ELSE
CONVERT(int,ReportIDTable.Salesrep) END)
LEFT JOIN invoice_hdr_salesrep WITH (NOLOCK)
ON invoice_hdr_salesrep.invoice_number = commission_sale_history.invoice_no
AND invoice_hdr_salesrep.salesrep_id = commission_sale_history.rep_id

WHERE ReportIDTable.ReportID = 1 
AND ReportIDTable.UserID = @UserID
AND ((Branch IN (@BranchID)) OR Branch = '9999')


AND commission_sale_history.rep_id IN(@SalesRepID)
AND commission_sale_history.invoice_date >= @InvoiceStartDate
AND commission_sale_history.payment_date
BETWEEN @PaymentFromDate AND @PaymentThroughDate
AND commission_sale_history.paid_in_full_flag = 'Y'
AND ISNULL(commission_sale_history.credit_matched_to_payment_flag,'Y') = 'Y'
AND commission_sale_history.product_division 
NOT IN ('Parts Sales', 'Rental', 'Forklift/Equipment', 'Service')
AND ISNULL(invoice_hdr_salesrep.primary_salesrep,'Y')='Y'

ORDER BY
commission_reps.rep_name,
customer.customer_id, 
commission_sale_history.invoice_no,
commission_sale_history.commission_type
```

Comment: I believe those multi-value parameters come over the wire as comma delimited strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the BranchID is and int and its name a string and therefore you branches dataset looks something like this.

```
BranchID BranchName
1        Chicago
2        New York
```

In your parameter, make sure your `Value` is pointing to the 'BranchID' column and `Label' is pointing the 'BranchName' column.

Once you have checked this, set your parameter value to be `text` (I know it's a number but try it....)

You don't need to use a stored proc, join or split, what you have should be fine.

If you still have problems, post the dataset query for both the main query and the parameter plus some sample output from each if possible.

Comment: I have updated my question above with the @BranchID parameter query.

Comment: OK, so you don't have a numeric ID column in your branch dataset. In that case I guess both your label and value point to the same `ParentID` column. Therefore the problem is actually with the `OR Branch = 9999` bit I think, remove this part of the WHERE clause and test.

Comment: That solved one of the issues! I can now select 1 Branch at a time and it will return data. If I still use the 'SELECT ALL' option, data is still displayed for all of the branches instead of only the two.

Comment: Can you show your main dataset query. I do this exact kind of report all the time and never have any issues so I'm puzzled. Also, when you say `Select All`, is this the built in option that just selects  everything in the parameters list? One last thing, if you drop your branch parameter down, are you getting the filtered list or branches or all of them?

Comment: It sounds like BRANCH is the BranchName and errors when it hits the second part of the **OR** where it compares it to an INT (due to ORDER PRECEDENCE and the first part being false). Sometimes the second part of the OR isn't evaluated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761019/do-all-parts-of-a-sql-server-expression-using-or-get-evaluated

Comment: @HannoverFist. Yes we've got that part fixed, The OP has removed the 2nd part of the where clause.

Comment: I have updated the question above with the main dataset query. Yes, the 'SELECT ALL' selects all of the options listed in the drop-down parameters list. I'm not filtering in the drop-down parameters list.

Comment: I can;t see anything obviously wrong with your query. The next thing I would do is comment out the BrandID part of the WHERE clause and run the query from the dataset designer passing in the UserID. I guess you would only expect to see records with the matching UserID. If all else fails, run a trace on the server and see exactly what query is being executed, that might give you a clue.

Comment: @AlanSchofield After filtering the parameters  list, everything is working great! Thanks!